# Firebase cloud function always returning null

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have tried to return the inner calls but my client still gets null values. I verified the function is behaving correctly by logging the functionality, but the client isn't getting the JSON I'm sending back.

```
// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
exports.validate = functions.https.onCall(async (data: any) => {
    return await receiptCallBack(data.receipt);
});

/**
 * 
 * @param receiptString specific per user
 * @param secretKey from Apple App Store
 */
const receiptCallBack = async function (receiptFromClient: String) {

    console.log("RECEIPT STRING FROM CLIENT IS " + receiptFromClient)

    // Callback version without device
    return await appleReceiptVerify.validate({
        receipt: receiptFromClient,
    }, (err: any, products: any) => {
        if (err) {
            return { result: console.error(err) };
        }
        // ok!
        // Can also just update your firestore database directly from here, thus updating the client thru that rather
        // than passing info back to client directly.

        for (const product of products) {
            if (product.productId === "V3Sub") {
                return {
                    result: "SUCCESS",
                    productId: product.productId,
                    expirationDate: product.expirationDate,
                    purchaseDate: product.purchaseDate,
                };

            }
        }
        return { result: "FAILURE TO GET PRODUCT" };

    });
}
```

Comment: The Firebase Function is not waiting for `receiptCallBack` to return. Try waiting for that specific function, log the result and return it. This way we should be able to see if the problem was there.

Comment: I added an await for receiptCallBack but it still fails.

Comment: It could be a good idea to show what class `appleReceiptVerify` is and what does the `verify` method do. It seems clear that, after adding the `await` clause, that function is not returning what it should. I still encourage you to log the return value of `receiptCallBack` and share with us its output.

Comment: I confirmed it is returning a list of JSON objects and I am able to parse it correctly. If I console.log out the productID, expirationDate, purchaseDate, it's all correctly logging out. Just not returning fine.

Comment: What happens if instead of `onCall(async (data: any) => {` you use `onRequest((request, response) => {`? Could you please try this?

Comment: The return should be changed to `response.json(<return_value>)`.

Comment: I'm calling it from a device so that's why I need to use onCall. onCall has a data and context parameter, so doesn't have a response

Comment: Then try to use `onCall((data, context) => {` and return as you are doing. Still, using `onRequest` allows you to call it from anywhere, you'd just have to use the HTTP endpoint.